# Jumping into iphone game development

Tags: iphone, ios

I am new on iphone, I have learned some iphone basics and made some sample codes. My lead wants me to jump into iphone game development, so I ll probably be working on a game like 'field runner' 2D game. Now tell me ppl how should I start my game development training ? **keeping in mind the game I am gona develop** and I will be given all characters by animators.
Any suggested tutorial or books ?, any specific engine to develop my future game ?

Thnx

Answer (score 2):

[Cocos2d](http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/) is a really awesome game engine that's super quick to learn and very powerful. For guided tutorials to get you started I recommend [Ray Wenderlich's blog](http://www.raywenderlich.com/352/how-to-make-a-simple-iphone-game-with-cocos2d-tutorial). Head over there and get started!